# AWS Cognito Incorrect Password limits

Tags: ios, passwords, amazon-cognito

We are currently working on a mobile application which is currently in beta version and plan to get it released to App Store very soon and this primarily supports only iOS mobile devices

Recently one of the external users had frantically typed a wrong password repeatedly in login screen which further exceeded the limit, resulting in an internal server error and finally locked the user out of the app

The default error messages come from AWS Cognito and the user is required to fill in the phone number and password to log in to the app

1. How many times will AWS Cognito allow the user to punch in incorrect passwords. Is there a limit to it
2. Is there any documentation which clearly explains my problem
3. Is there a way to let the user know at the first instance say., that there are only 5 attempts to try

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

According to AWS Cognito docs,there are no limits on login attempts, however they do secure login endpoint with request rate limiting and exponential timeouts:

> We allow five failed sign-in attempts. After that we start temporary lockouts with exponentially increasing times starting at 1 second and doubling after each failed attempt up to about 15 minutes. Attempts during a temporary lockout period are ignored. After the temporary lockout period, if the next attempt fails, a new temporary lockout starts with twice the duration as the last. Waiting about 15 minutes without any attempts will also reset the temporary lockout. Please note that this behavior is subject to change.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html